Design Time drag-drop support
I have a usercontrol with two panels (kpnlFilter and kpnlDetail) in it.
I was able to enable them as drop zones for design time with the following codes:
this.EnableDesignMode(((mGridHolder)this.Control).kpnlFilter, "DropZone_Filter");
this.EnableDesignMode(((mGridHolder)this.Control).kpnlDetail, "DropZone_Detail");

But I could not get any drag events (DragDrop, DragEnter, DragLeave, DragOver) to work in DESIGNTIME (runtime works).
The goal is to catch dropped controls in designtime.
Thanks for any help.
Best Regards.
